# Git not converting line endings to LF on commit

Tags: git, git-commit, line-endings

Even when setting `core.autocrlf=true` we are still seeing line endings committed as CRLF instead of LF (I can see the `^M` symbol when running `git diff` and `git log -p`)

This is causing merge conflicts sometimes as different developers use different settings in their editors.

How can we fix this with minimal future conflicts in a very active repository environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I generally recommend using `.gitattributes` here, rather than setting `core.autocrlf` (not that I actually deal with this, but that's how the Git project folks do it, and presumably they know).

*.gitattributes* example:

```
*.ts        text eol=lf
```

That's not going to fix your problems, but it should help avoid *new* problems in the future.

To handle merge issues, consider running:

```
git merge -X renormalize
```

and/or setting `merge.renormalize` to `true`.

## Long: why

It's worth pointing out that Git *never* does *any* conversions on *commit*.  **The mechanism that implements CRLF-to-LF-only conversion sits not in `git commit`, but rather in `git add`.**  To see why, we must start with a few Git basics:

- Each commit has a full snapshot of every file (that Git knew about at the time you, or whoever, made the commit).  (Each commit also has some metadata, but this is not relevant to this particular issue.)
- No commit, once made, can ever be changed.  Once some file is in a commit, it's inviolate.
- The files stored inside a commit are not stored as ordinary files.  Instead, they're stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed (sometimes highly compressed) and de-duplicated form.  The de-duplication takes care of the fact that most commits mostly use the *same* copies of files as some other earlier commit.  But this also means that you literally can't work on / with *these* copies of the files.
- The snapshot for a *new* commit comes not from your working tree copies of files, but rather from *Git's* "copies" of files as they appear in GIt's *index*.

The index is also called the *staging area*, which is a better name in terms of how users use it, although the ways Git uses it go beyond this (which is why it has the name *cache* as well, giving it three names: *cache*, *index*, and *staging area*).  In any case, these extra "copies" of files exist, in Git's index.  I put "copies" in quotes here because what's in the index is *already in the special form Git uses*.  These are not ordinary files and cannot be edited either (they *can* be *replaced* though).

Instead, there's a *third* copy of every file.  This third copy *is* an ordinary file.  These are the files that you can see and edit.  The catch is that these files *are not in Git*.  They are extracted *from* Git during `git checkout` or `git switch`, or when using `git reset` or `git restore` for instance.

During extraction, Git has two options: it can leave the file alone, or it can change it.  The change can include replacing LF-only line endings with CRLF line endings.  You now have a file you can look at.  If you choose to have files extracted such that they have CRLF line endings, you also have configured Git, at this point, to make "undo CRLF line endings" changes if and when you have Git replace the index copy.

What `git add` does is tell Git: *Make the index copy match the working tree copy.*  **If you've changed the working tree copy** Git will now compress and Git-ify the working tree copy and use that to replace the copy that is in the index.  Unfortunately for CRLF-line-ending-fixing, if Git thinks that there's no *need* to replace the index copy, Git does nothing at all.<sup>1</sup>

Unfortunately, Git checks neither `core.autocrlf` nor any settings in `.gitattributes` when deciding whether or not it needs to replace the index copy of some file.  So changing either of these does not count as a "change" to any file.<sup>2</sup>  In Git 2.16 and later, `git add --renormalize` helps tell Git: *Hey, you dummy, I changed my EOL conversions, so adding a file changes it even if I haven't changed it.*  In Git versions predating 2.16, you must *trick Git into believing that you changed the file* if all you're trying to do is fix the line endings.  (There are a bunch of ways to do that, but let's just pretend you have `git add --renormalize`. )

Think of Git's index as holding the *proposed* next commit.  When you run `git commit`, Git simply snapshots the index.  Since it already holds Git-ified files, this goes pretty fast.

In any case, the end result here is this:

- At the time Git copies a file from Git's index—or with `git restore`, from a commit—to your working tree, Git applies the "make the file useful to you, personally" end-of-line changes.
- At the time Git copies a file from your working tree to Git's index, Git applies the "make the file normalized for the repository" changes.

When you run `git commit`, Git uses the copy that is *in Git's index* to make the commit.  So whatever line endings appear in the *index* copy, those are the line endings that go into the permanent copy in a new commit.  *You* can't *see* those copies, but `git ls-files` can.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually re-compressing a file into the Git format is a lot of work, so Git cleverly avoids it whenever possible.  That's one of the reasons that Git's index *exists*.  Other version control systems get by without one; other version control systems are slower.  The problem here is just that Git thinks that this work-avoidance is possible *too often*.

<sup>2</sup>Of course, if you modify `.gitattributes`, Git will realize that `.gitattributes` is modified.  It's just that it never extends that to thinking: *Oh hey!  Maybe that means other files have EOL settings changed.*

---

#### `core.autocrlf` vs `.gitattributes`

There are a bunch of differences between using `core.autocrlf` and using `.gitattributes` to specify in-repository line-ending formats.  The biggest and most obvious is of course that `core.autocrlf` is a setting everyone has to make in their personal `.git/config` or `$HOME/.gitconfig` or wherever they like to put it, but `.gitattributes` is a *committed file*.

Being a committed file has a bunch of ramifications: in particular, you get the existing one when you check out some commit.  There's a copy of that file in *each* commit—well, each commit made when `.gitattributes` was in Git's index at the time whoever made the commit, made the commit—and when you check out that commit, Git obeys that commit's `.gitattributes` settings.  When you `git add` files, Git obeys your working tree's `.gitattributes` settings, so you can change the settings and `git add` files—including `.gitattributes`—and your updated settings will apply *and* will go into the next commit.

Importantly, when listing files in `.gitattributes`, *you are in control*.  You can tell Git that file `xyz` is a binary file, if it is binary.  You can tell Git that file `abc` is a text file, if it is text.  You can say that `*.js` or `*.py` are text and that `*.jpg` are binary.  When you use `core.autocrlf`, you're just having Git *guess*.  Git can guess wrong, and do CRLF changes to your binary files, or not do them to your text files.

For details on what to put in a `.gitattributes` file, see [the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

#### The renormalize option

When you use `git merge` to do a three-way merge,<sup>3</sup> there are three input commits: the current commit, the commit you select via the command line, and the merge base.  You can normalize line endings in your current commit, by just making a new commit with the fixed line endings.  If you really had to, you could check out the commit you are about to select on the command line, normalize its line endings, and commit that too, and use that one on the command line instead.  But you literally *can't* fix the merge-base commit: Git finds this one on its own, based on the commit graph—the linkage between commits as stored in the commits' metadata.

Line endings matter to `git diff`, and the merge depends on the two diffs (from the merge base to your commit, and from the merge base to the commit you select).  So it is sometimes necessary to fix the merge base, as well as the current commit and the other commit.  The renormalize option does exactly that.  This way, there's no need to do the impossible—to fix historical commits' line endings.  A merge that requires renormalizing goes a little slower, but that's better than not going at all.

---

<sup>3</sup>Remember that `git merge` might instead do a *fast-forward merge*, which is not a merge at all.

Comment: Very useful, thanks. But shifting the focus from `commit`  to `add` does not explain, why sometimes files with CRLF keep showing up in the repo, despite all users having `core.autocrlf` set. Furthermore, after fixing the repo, how can one make sure the fresh files (with fixed eol) are copied into working trees, once you checkout over an existing working tree? We want them all in LF now, tried `.gitattributes` with `* -text`, which does not replace working tree files, and with `* text=auto eol=lf` which seems to do it, but why? According to your explanation, it should not.

Comment: If you ever see that files appear to be modified on initial checkout/clone, this means that the *in-repository* files have CRLF line endings and you've asked for them not to have those. It is impossible to change any *commits* so the existing commits are now automatically "wrong"; *future* commits can be corrected by adding (with renormalization if needed). (Be aware that there are other sources of this same "files are modified even on fresh clone" problem too though: in particular if you make repositories on Linux, and clone them to Windows/MacOS, you can get file name case issues.)

Comment: Getting your `.gitattributes` right is important, but note that any individual user can still break things if they work at it. :-) As for `* text=auto`: I dislike this because it means: *Hey Git, guess for me whether this file is to be `text` or `-text`!* and Git isn't *clever*, though it does have a lot of practical experience embedded in it at this point. `eol=lf` just means that if a file is going to be treated as text, the in-working-tree copy will have LF-only line endings.

Comment: The answer above is all about *putting files into Git* (into the index and hence on into future commits), but the `eol=` setting is also about *taking files out of Git*. If a file is marked for conversions, Git can, during the take-out-of-commit/index copy-to-working-tree-ordinary-file step, replace LF-only line endings with CRLF line endings. That's the only change Git will ever make "on the way out": if the file is committed with CRLF line endings, it will wind up with CRLF line endings in your working tree.

Comment: Short summary (if it's not too late...): "on way out" (index->working tree) Git can turn \n into \r\n. It does so if: conversions enabled, eol=CRLF. Meanwhile "on way in" (working tree->index) Git can turn \r\n into \n. It does so if: conversions enabled. Because compressing and Git-ifying a file is expensive (in CPU time), Git tries to avoid the working tree->index conversion as much as possible; `--renormalize` is a way to force it to do the conversion anyway. (all @markus)

Comment: Thanks, @torek. Goals: a) have all files normalized to LF in the repo (we did that), b) use LF on Windows too, modern tools seem ok with that, c) still convert CRLF to LF if a user/tool misbehaves, d) if a user has an old working tree state (from before we added `.gitattributes`) and then checks out a newer commit, files should be overwritten with LF, even if not actually changed between the commits. In other words: I wonder if git does the same optimization "on the way out" that you described "on the way in", i.e. is it the same "dummy" about `.gitattributes` that have since changed?

Comment: It will in fact do that on the way out (the "cheating"/optimization for speed and other reasons) if you have files left around from previous commits. The safe way to sidestep that problem is to make a new clone (`git clone` again), or a new working tree (`git worktree add`). The unsafe (but not that unsafe if you're *careful*) way is to remove and re-check-out each file.

Comment: The "problem" is this: we tried `* text=auto eol=lf` and it seems to work, all files seem to be replaced with LF. It even works the other way around, we can go to a stable branch (where `.gitattributes` is not yet present, as this is still in testing) and it will go back to CRLF on Windows. So I'm now confused and sort of don't trust it... >¦-/

Comment: @markus: if you still have `core.autocrlf` set, the lack of a `.gitattributes` means `* text=auto`, and the lack of `eol=lf` means, on Windows, `eol=crlf`. So that would all make sense. If you have `core.autocrlf` turned off (set to `false`), you'll be getting whatever's actually in those commits.

Comment: Exactly. We'll just trust it for the moment. Thanks.

Comment: Great answer @torek - .gitattributes is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it has something to do with git not "normalizing" files that were purposely changed. Ordinarily when a new file is introduced it gets converted to LF and "normalized" but, if someone edits the line endings without autocrlf set, they will be changed and then git won't care.

I can see a list of files that are set that way by running

`git ls-files --eol`

When you see `i/crlf` or `i/mixed` that file is not "normalized" and git won't force conversion to LF.

Looks like there may be a few approaches to fix this, but I will wait for others to chime in.

UPDATE: Answer by @torek is very good, especially using `.gitattributes` -- that has been the key safety setting for us with. enterprise work over the last couple of years.

The following .gitattribute file will force convert all your typescript lines to LF, whenever someone edits anything at all in that file and commits it (it will change the index, not their local working branch):

```
*.ts        text eol=lf
```